# How to draw the Gaussian graphical model in R

Tags: r, model, correlation, gaussian

I have got the Correlation coefficient matrix R, and the Partial correlation coefficient matrix Rp, then how could I draw the Gaussian graphical model in R?

It would be better if recommending some books introduction about the Gaussian graphical model, indeed, I don't know what is it, but the first thing I need to do is to draw it out. Many thanks!

```
#the Correlation coefficient matrix
R=c(1,0.55,0.55,0.41,0.39,0.55,1,0.61,0.49,0.44,0.55,0.61,1,0.71,
0.66,0.41,0.49,0.71,1,0.61,0.39,0.44,0.66,0.61,1)
dim(R)=c(5,5)

#the Partial correlation coefficient matrix
library("corpcor") 
Rp=cor2pcor(R)
```

Then how could I draw the Gaussian graphical model?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to plot the corresponding graph, you can use the `igraph` package.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency( abs(Rp)>.1, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE )
plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

Comment: Otherwise you will always have a complete graph, which is rather uninformative. Alternatively, one could use a fainter colour when the correlation is low, as in Sacha's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the term "Gaussian graphical model" although I feel I should be (I'll read up on it, thanks).

But to visualize (partial) correlation matrices you could use the `qgraph` package, which is designed to do just that. For example:

```
library("qgraph")
qgraph(round(Rp,5),edge.labels=TRUE)
```

[image]

Computing partial correlations are built in with the `graph` argument:

```
qgraph(round(R,5),edge.labels=TRUE,graph="concentration")
```

Gives the same result.

Comment: I was fail to get the package "qgraph": Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
you need the DLL'plyr'

Comment: Installing via CRAN should install `plyr` as well automatically. `install.packages("qgraph",dep=TRUE)`. Make sure your R version is up to date (2.15).